# Converting makefile into its relavant cmakefile

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I have a makeFile I need to have the same cmake file,
 I dont want to convert it manually because it will take my time, is it any tool or any solution to make this solution automatic?

Comment: I'm a fried - no. But you will find creating CMakeLists.txt is much easiest then you can expect.

Comment: I know its easy to write cmake file but in general is it any solution  for such a problem, I don't want to write it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of what is available is covered by CMake's Wiki ["Converters from other buildsystems to CMake"](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/Home#converters-from-other-buildsystems-to-cmake) chapter.

But be aware - keeping in mind the complexity you could put into an `makefile` and the fact that [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake) is an abstraction layer hiding some of this complexity - the following hint from the Wiki page linked above:

> All converters listed here are not "complete", i.e. the generated CMake
>   files are not 100% finished, **in all cases some work is left for the
>   developer**.

So to setup and maintain CMake, you first need to learn what CMake is and can do for you.

**Reference**

- [How to frame the concept behind CMake?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/299929/how-to-frame-the-concept-behind-cmake)